# Why can't I assign a embedded struct to a parent struct in go?

Tags: go, struct

I have below code try to assign embed struct to its parent struct. There are two set of structure: `Guider` is the parent struct, `DataBlock` extends from it. The method `func Put(x Guider)` accept a parameter with type `Guider`. It works when I pass a `DataBlock` variable.

However, the other case is `Mock` extends from `zerolog.Event`, but it fails to pass the parameter on the method `Test(e zerolog.Event)`

I got the following error:

> cannot use m (variable of type Mock) as type zerolog.Event in argument to Test

Why are these two cases works differently? How can I make them both work?

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/rs/zerolog"
)

type Guider interface {
    Guid() string
}
type FSEntity struct {
    guid string
}

func (e FSEntity) Guid() string {
    return e.guid
}

func Put(x Guider) {
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)

}

type Mock struct {
    zerolog.Event
}

func Test(e zerolog.Event) {

}

//Child struct:

type DataBlock struct {
    FSEntity
    data []byte
}

func main() {
    myVar := DataBlock{}
    myVar.guid = "test"
    myVar.data = []byte("moar test")
    Put(myVar) // it works

    m := Mock{}
    Test(m) // it doesn't work. cannot use m (variable of type Mock) as type zerolog.Event in argument to Test
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a couple of definitions:

[**Polymorphism**](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

Polymorphism is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types or the use of a single symbol to represent multiple different types.

[**Subtyping**](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Subtyping)

Subtyping (also subtype polymorphism or inclusion polymorphism) is a form of type polymorphism in which a subtype is a datatype that is related to another datatype (the supertype) by some notion of substitutability, meaning that program elements, typically subroutines or functions, written to operate on elements of the supertype can also operate on elements of the subtype

[**Inheritance**](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

In object-oriented programming, inheritance is the mechanism of basing an object or class upon another object (prototype-based inheritance) or class (class-based inheritance), retaining similar implementation.

[**Object composition**](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Object_composition)

Object composition and object aggregation are closely related ways to combine objects or data types into more complex ones.

---

Golang follows [composition over inheritance principle](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Composition_over_inheritance), e.g. it doesn't support inheritance. So when you're saying

> Mock extends from zerolog.Event

you actually mean that `Mock` **includes** `zerolog.Event` struct.

The way Golang implements polymorphism is `interface`. All types that implement some interface can be used in its place. It's what you see when use `Guider`.

However, it doesn't work for simple structs. `zerolog.Event` is a struct inside `Mock`.

So, normally, `Test` function should accept some interface as a parameter, and both mock and real event should implement this interface. However, it looks like zerolog doesn't provide interface for Event. So instead you should access the `Event` field of you struct. [Example](https://go.dev/play/p/Mj_HNTYAxDC)

Answer (score 2):

`Put(myVar)` is legal because `myVar` is a `DataBlock` which *contains* (not inherits from and not implements) an `FSEntity` which in turn *implements* the `Guider` interface.

Since `Put` accepts a `Guider`, the reference to `myVar` is compatible, by virtue of the anonymous `FSEntity` field it contains which implements `Guider`.  The implementation of `Guider` on `FSEntity` is (in effect) elevated to the containing struct (providing a means of delegating interfaces).  This only occurs if the contained field is anonymous.

But in the case of `Test(m)`, the function accepts a `zerolog.Event` which is a `struct` type, not an `interface`.  As such, there is no "delegation" possible.  `Test()` must be passed a `zerolog.Event` and in this scenario, this requires that you use the type name of the anonymous field:

```golang
Type(m.Event)
```

Some bonus info:

If `DataBlock` contained *two* anonymous fields which both implemented `Guider` then implicit delegation/elevation cannot take place; golang does not know which of the contained implementations should be delegated to/elevated (if any).  In that scenario you must again use the name of the field that you wish to pass to the `Put()` function:

```golang
   // given... 
   type Foo string

   func (f Foo) Guid() string {
      return string(f)
   }

   // and...
   type DataBlock struct {
      FSEntity
      Foo
      data []byte
   }

   // then...
   Put(myVar)   // is now illegal

   // and must instead use either/or:
   Put(myVar.FSEntity)
   Put(myVar.Foo)
```

Whether implicit or explicit, the crucial distinction is that it is a *field* of the `DataBlock` (`myVar`) that is passed to `Put()`, **not** `myVar` itself.

If you want to pass the `DataBlock` to `Put()`, using a `Guider` interface, then `DataBlock` must itself implement the `Guider` interface.

Answer (score 0):

Take this with a grain of salt, since I'm not familiar with `zerolog` package.

Your `Guider` is an interface, which might have any underlying type as long as `Guid()` method is satisfied. I assume this is happening through `DataBlock` containing `FSEntity`, which itself implements `Guid()` method, therefore satisfies MIGHT the interface.

On the other hand, I don't know what methods should be implemented to satisfy `zerolog.Event` or if it's even an interface, or a struct straight up. If it's an interface, you might need to implement it's required methods to be able to use `DataBlock` as `zerolog.Event` type. You might want/need to dig into that direction for some very specific answers.